# JavaScript function doesn't return correct amount of answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a quiz that I am working on, but one of the issues that I am running into is that regardless of how many questions a user answers incorrectly, the results page always states that all 10 questions were answered correctly.

I need it to keep track of how many questions were answered incorrectly and then display the correct score. For example: 5 out of 10 answered correctly, 7 out of 10 answered correctly etc. Would someone be able to look my code over and tell me what it is that I am needing to fix?

```js
let score = 0;
    let currentQuestion = 0;
    let questions = [{
        title: "At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
        answers: ['7', '10', '11', '13'],
        correct: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
        answers: ['Dunder Mifflin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Slytherin', 'Gryffindor'],
        correct: 0
      },
      {
        title: "Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
        answers: ['Rubeus Hagrid', 'Albus Dumbledore', 'Severus Snape', 'Minerva McGonnagle'],
        correct: 3
      },
      {
        title: "Where is Hogwarts School for Witchcraft and Wizardry located?",
        answers: ['France', 'USA', 'UK', 'New Zealand'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What form does Harry Potter's patronus charm take?",
        answers: ['Stag', 'Eagle', 'Bear', 'Dragon'],
        correct: 0
      },
      {
        title: "What type of animal is Harry's pet?",
        answers: ['Dog', 'Owl', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
        correct: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Who is not a member of the Order of the Phoenix?",
        answers: ['Remus Lupin', 'Siruis Black', 'Lucious Malfoy', 'Severus Snape'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What is not a piece of the Deathly Hallows?",
        answers: ['Elder Wand', 'Cloak of Invisibility', 'Resurrection Stone', 'Sword of Gryffindor'],
        correct: 3
      },
      {
        title: "In which house is Harry sorted into after arriving at Hogwarts?",
        answers: ['Slytherin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Gryffindor', 'Hufflepuff'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What prevented Voldemort from being able to kill Harry Potter when he was a baby?",
        answers: ['Love', 'Anger', 'Friendship', 'Joy'],
        correct: 0
      },
    ];



    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.start a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.start').hide();
        $('.quiz').show();
        showQuestion();
      });

      $('.quiz ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
      });

      $('.quiz a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('li.selected').length) {
          let guess = parseInt($('li.selected').attr('id'));
          checkAnswer(guess);
        } else {
          alert('Please select an answer');
        }
      });

      $('.summary a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        restartQuiz();
      });

    });

    function showQuestion() {
      let question = questions[currentQuestion];
      $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
      $('.quiz ul').html('');
      for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
        $('.quiz ul').append(`<li id="${i}">${question.answers[i]}</li>`);
      }
      showProgress();
    }

    function showIncorrectQuestion(guess) {
        let question = questions[currentQuestion];
        $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
        $('.quiz ul').html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
            let cls = i === question.correct ? "selected" : guess === i ? "wrong" : ""
            $('.quiz ul').append(`<li id="${i}" class="${cls}">${question.answers[i]}</li>`);
        }
        showProgress();
    }

    function checkAnswer(guess) {
        let question = questions[currentQuestion];
        if (question.correct === guess) {
            score++;
            showIsCorrect(true);
            currentQuestion++;
            if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
                showSummary();
            } else {
                showQuestion();
            }
        } else {
            showIsCorrect(false);
            showIncorrectQuestion(guess);
        }


    }

    function showSummary() {
      $('.quiz').hide();
      $('.summary').show();
      $('.summary p').text("Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered " + score + " out of " + questions.length + " correctly! Care to try again?")
    }

    function restartQuiz() {
      $('.summary').hide();
      $('.quiz').show();
      score = 0;
      currentQuestion = 0;
      showQuestion();
    }

    function showProgress() {
      $('#currentQuestion').html(currentQuestion + " out of " + questions.length);
    }

    function showIsCorrect(isCorrect) {
      var result = "Wrong";
      if (isCorrect) {
        result = "Correct";
      }
      $('#isCorrect').html(result);
    }
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  background-color: #950002;
  padding: 60px;
  color: #FFAB0D;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: #950002;
  color: #FFAB0D;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

p {
 font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  background-color: #FFAB0D;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;

}

a {
  border: 1px solid #222F5B;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #222F5B;
  color: silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FCBF2B;
}

.quiz li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 26px;
}

#currentQuestion {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

#isCorrect {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;

}

.quiz, .summary {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .quiz ul {
      margin-top: 20px;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .selected {
      background-color: #398C3F;
    }

.wrong {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="start">
    <h1>How Well Do You Know Harry Potter?</h1>
    <a href="#">Start Quiz</a>
  </div>


  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Question Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">Submit Answer</a>
    <div id="currentQuestion"></div>
    <div id="isCorrect"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="summary">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <p>Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered x out of y correctly! Care to try again?</p>
    <a href="#">Retake Quiz</a>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your logic is this.  When someone clicks the submit answer button, check if the selected answer is correct, otherwise select the correct answer and require the user to press the button again.  Do you see the problem?  (it will always be correct the second time they press the button cuz you select the right answer for them)

Comment: That makes sense and looking at it again I can't believe that I didn't see that the first time around, so thank you. If I may ask, how would you solve and rewrite that function so that it would do what I am wanting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep track of whether a question has been answered once already.  If it has, pressing check answer won't increase the score.

We can store the "alreadyAnswered" property in the question object for the current question.  If it doesn't exist then it's false.

The code change is quite simple:

```
function checkAnswer(guess) {
    let question = questions[currentQuestion];
    if (question.correct === guess) {
        // only update score if not already answered
        if (!question.alreadyAnswered) {
          score++;
        }
        showIsCorrect(true);
        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
            showSummary();
        } else {
            showQuestion();
        }
    } else {
        showIsCorrect(false);
        showIncorrectQuestion(guess);
    }
    // mark this question as already answered
    question.alreadyAnswered = true;
}
```

Additionally, to address the problem of all questions marked as "answered" when we retake the quiz:

```
function restartQuiz() {
  // reset "alreadyAnswered" flags
  questions.forEach(q => q.alreadyAnswered = false);

  $('.summary').hide();
  $('.quiz').show();
  score = 0;
  currentQuestion = 0;
  showQuestion();
}
```

The entire snippet:

```js
let score = 0;
    let currentQuestion = 0;
    let questions = [{
        title: "At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
        answers: ['7', '10', '11', '13'],
        correct: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
        answers: ['Dunder Mifflin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Slytherin', 'Gryffindor'],
        correct: 0
      },
      {
        title: "Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
        answers: ['Rubeus Hagrid', 'Albus Dumbledore', 'Severus Snape', 'Minerva McGonnagle'],
        correct: 3
      },
      {
        title: "Where is Hogwarts School for Witchcraft and Wizardry located?",
        answers: ['France', 'USA', 'UK', 'New Zealand'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What form does Harry Potter's patronus charm take?",
        answers: ['Stag', 'Eagle', 'Bear', 'Dragon'],
        correct: 0
      },
      {
        title: "What type of animal is Harry's pet?",
        answers: ['Dog', 'Owl', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
        correct: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Who is not a member of the Order of the Phoenix?",
        answers: ['Remus Lupin', 'Siruis Black', 'Lucious Malfoy', 'Severus Snape'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What is not a piece of the Deathly Hallows?",
        answers: ['Elder Wand', 'Cloak of Invisibility', 'Resurrection Stone', 'Sword of Gryffindor'],
        correct: 3
      },
      {
        title: "In which house is Harry sorted into after arriving at Hogwarts?",
        answers: ['Slytherin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Gryffindor', 'Hufflepuff'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What prevented Voldemort from being able to kill Harry Potter when he was a baby?",
        answers: ['Love', 'Anger', 'Friendship', 'Joy'],
        correct: 0
      },
    ];



    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.start a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.start').hide();
        $('.quiz').show();
        showQuestion();
      });

      $('.quiz ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
      });

      $('.quiz a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('li.selected').length) {
          let guess = parseInt($('li.selected').attr('id'));
          checkAnswer(guess);
        } else {
          alert('Please select an answer');
        }
      });

      $('.summary a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        restartQuiz();
      });

    });

    function showQuestion() {
      let question = questions[currentQuestion];
      $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
      $('.quiz ul').html('');
      for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
        $('.quiz ul').append(`<li id="${i}">${question.answers[i]}</li>`);
      }
      showProgress();
    }

    function showIncorrectQuestion(guess) {
        let question = questions[currentQuestion];
        $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
        $('.quiz ul').html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
            let cls = i === question.correct ? "selected" : guess === i ? "wrong" : ""
            $('.quiz ul').append(`<li id="${i}" class="${cls}">${question.answers[i]}</li>`);
        }
        showProgress();
    }

    function checkAnswer(guess) {
        let question = questions[currentQuestion];
        if (question.correct === guess) {
            if (!question.alreadyAnswered) {
              score++;
            }
            showIsCorrect(true);
            currentQuestion++;
            if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
                showSummary();
            } else {
                showQuestion();
            }
        } else {
            showIsCorrect(false);
            showIncorrectQuestion(guess);
        }
        question.alreadyAnswered = true;
    }

    function showSummary() {
      $('.quiz').hide();
      $('.summary').show();
      $('.summary p').text("Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered " + score + " out of " + questions.length + " correctly! Care to try again?")
    }

    function restartQuiz() {
      // reset "alreadyAnswered" flags
      questions.forEach(q => q.alreadyAnswered = false);
      
      $('.summary').hide();
      $('.quiz').show();
      score = 0;
      currentQuestion = 0;
      showQuestion();
    }

    function showProgress() {
      $('#currentQuestion').html(currentQuestion + " out of " + questions.length);
    }

    function showIsCorrect(isCorrect) {
      var result = "Wrong";
      if (isCorrect) {
        result = "Correct";
      }
      $('#isCorrect').html(result);
    }
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  background-color: #950002;
  padding: 60px;
  color: #FFAB0D;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: #950002;
  color: #FFAB0D;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

p {
 font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  background-color: #FFAB0D;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;

}

a {
  border: 1px solid #222F5B;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #222F5B;
  color: silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FCBF2B;
}

.quiz li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 26px;
}

#currentQuestion {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

#isCorrect {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;

}

.quiz, .summary {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .quiz ul {
      margin-top: 20px;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .selected {
      background-color: #398C3F;
    }

.wrong {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="start">
    <h1>How Well Do You Know Harry Potter?</h1>
    <a href="#">Start Quiz</a>
  </div>


  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Question Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">Submit Answer</a>
    <div id="currentQuestion"></div>
    <div id="isCorrect"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="summary">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <p>Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered x out of y correctly! Care to try again?</p>
    <a href="#">Retake Quiz</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me how to fix that, I appreciate it! I did notice that when the user clicks 'retake quiz' no matter how they answer the next go around of questions, the results screen always states that they have answered "0 out of 10" correctly. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Yes!  Because question.alreadyAnswered will be true still.  So, in restartQuiz, we’ll have to set them all to false.

Comment: I tried setting them to false under restartQuiz, but I wasn't able to fix it. Would you mind showing me the syntax that you would use? I really appreciate your help by the way!

Comment: I updated my answer.  The snippet runner isn’t working for me though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the `showIncorrectQuestion()` function - when user selects invalid question, you are showing a valid answer and at the same time programatically "choose" it (setting correct answer as chosen by the user not only showing that this one was the valid one).

Then, to go to the next question, user has to click on "Submit" again and when `checkAnswer()` is called again this time (as it is called each time user clicks "Submit"), it will be validated as correct answer and `score` will be increased, showing `10` on the end no matter if user has chosen correct or incorrect answer.

Comment: That makes sense. If I may ask, how would you solve and rewrite that function so that it would do what I am wanting?